# Pass pickle from Python to IronPython - cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid opcode: x

Tags: python, pickle, ironpython

Newbie to IronPython here.

I am trying to load a pickle file in IronPython that was creating using Python. Here's how the pickle was created:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
import joblib

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor()
joblib.dump(gp, 'krigingModel.pkl')
joblib.dump(joblib.load('krigingModel.pkl'), 'krigingModelp2.pkl', 2)
```

Here's my attempt at loading the pickle in IronPython:

```
import cPickle as pickle

filename = 'krigingModelp2.pkl'
infile = open(filename, 'rb')
new_dict = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()
print new_dict
```

This results in the following error:

```
cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid opcode: x
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Which Python version was used for the export? IronPython may not support the same pickle protocol.

Comment: Just updated the original post - exported using protocol 2, as 3 was causing this error in IronPython:
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3

Comment: Weird, though – opcode `x` doesn't seem to be a thing (`X` is): https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d8ca2354ed30c12b9ce37c4535222b700a727b32/Lib/pickle.py#L130 ... `x` could be a joblib extension. Can you use `joblib.load()` in IronPython?

Comment: Why are you reloading and dumping the pickle file, rather than dumping the original object using protocol 2?

Comment: @AKX as far as I'm aware, IronPython doesn't support joblib

Comment: @jasonharper just so I can access the pickle using Python 2 or 3